# How to include tracing for requests propagated using NestJS?

Tags: trace, nestjs, istio, jaeger

I'm setting up Jager tracing in Istio, but I cannot figure out how i should propagate the headers required in NestJS.

I've searched around in documentation for injection per request, but cant really wrap my head around it.

The headers that needs to be propagated are the following:

```
x-request-id
x-b3-traceid
x-b3-spanid
x-b3-parentspanid
x-b3-sampled
x-b3-flags
x-ot-span-context
```

Comment: Can you share your deployment? How did you set it up?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward, all of my services are general deployments using kubernetes. Istio works perfectly fine for Prometheus/Grafana but to make Jaeger with I should pass in the header information necessary for Jaeger. How do we intercept the request header information and inject these same header information to the response in nestjs

Answer (score 3):

I used the [hpropagate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hpropagate) npm package to get this working on my Istio cluster. It takes care of all the heavy lifting of extracting the trace headers from the incoming request and appending them to any outbound requests.

**Install**

```
npm install hpropagate
```

**Usage**

In `main.ts`, import the package and call the function (with whatever [default overrides](https://github.com/WealthWizardsEngineering/hpropagate#override-defaults) you need) before creating the Nest app.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import hpropagate from 'hpropagate';

async function bootstrap() {

  hpropagate({
    setAndPropagateCorrelationId: false,
  });

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

For more info, check out this article: https://medium.com/ww-engineering/headers-propagation-with-hpropagate-27de8347f76a